# Trying to pull a users score from firebase realtime database

Tags: java

I am trying to create a leaderboard within my app. 
So far a I have a database that contains a users information, including their score.
I am trying to create a leaderboard whereby I pull the score of each user from the firebase database and present it on screen in a leaderboard section of my app.

Is it possible to retrieve only the username and score for each user and display this on a screen?
Thanks

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        databaseUsers = database.getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_score);

        String leaderboard = String.valueOf(databaseUsers.child(mAuth).child("score"));
        score.setText(leaderboard);


    }

}
```

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

public class Users {

    String username;
    String job;
    String email;
    String office;
    Integer score;

    public Users() {

    }
    public static String currentUserId;
    public static Users currentUser;



    public Users(String username, String job, String email, String office, Integer score) {
        this.username = username;
        this.job = job;
        this.email = email;
        this.office = office;
        this.score = score;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getOffice() {
        return office;
    }

    public void setOffice(String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }

    public Integer getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }




}
```